# PDO query bindValue and % returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, substring

i don't understand why my query returns no results

```
<?php
    include "connection.php";

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM my_tb WHERE column1 = :par1 ');
    $stmt->bindValue(':par1', '%'.$_POST['submit1'].'%');
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            print_r($row[0]); 
            print_r($row[1]);
            print_r($row[2]);
        };  
?>
```

when i change `'%'.$_POST['submit1'].'%'` to `$_POST['submit1']`  its working fine.
i am searching for a substring

Comment: Before trying to get result via your application, you should try your query directly in the console or whatever you use to execute a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want wildcard matching, you're looking for a `LIKE` query, not a `=` comparison.

```
SELECT * FROM my_tb WHERE column1 LIKE :par1
```